# getting the value of a tensor flow placeholder during session

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a model (which is not originally written by me) and I am trying to learn about the code and doing some modifications.

suppose I have some placeholders defined as (Here I have written just one):

```
fs = [tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(n,  m))  for i in range(k)]
```

After making the `feed_dict` and during the Session, I would like to print the values fed into the placeholders and for example doing some operations.

**How can I get the value of a placeholder during run and then print them?**

I found for example `tf.eval()` is a way, but it makes the computation graph from scratch, which is not good for my case.

I couldn't find answer on the web. So I appreciate if you can help me on that.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `session.run`, e.g.

```
fs_results = session.run(fs, feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

This does not create a new computational graph from scratch.

Comment: Wont it affect on other computations?

Comment: No, returning the value does not affect any computations